# Background jobs identification

Tags: background, abap, jobs, foreground

After a job has been executed (the job is already finished), how will you know, if it ran via foreground or background?

Do I go to sm37 and see it there? When I select the job name and type JDBG, I still don't see it.

Comment: How did you schedule the job in the first place? Why do you doubt if / assume that it ran in the foreground/background when you scheduled it yourself? You should know.

Comment: If you want to have this information just log it by yourself (if it is your own program). Standard programs should have this information logged in in a BAL or system log anyways. You can check if program runs in the background by reading the `sy-batch` flag.

Answer (score 3):

The foreground jobs does not have an entry in SM37. SM37 is only for the scheduled background jobs. I hope you are not confused between dialog jobs and dialog work  processes.

A dialog work process has a run-time limit that prevents users from running long reports. Background work processes allocate memory differently than dialog work processes so that background work processes can become as large as they need to in allocated memory to allow for processing large volumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

In SM37, you need to have the checkbox next to the job name checked and then type jdbg. When you press enter the debugger should popup.

Edit: Typo